# Call object specific method from abstract list in C#

Tags: c#, oop

I have a list of abstract classes like

```
List<Animal> animalList = new List<Animal>();
```

I iterate over the list by doing

```
foreach(Animal a in animalList.Values){
  if(a is Monkey){
    //Call monkey specific method
    a.PeelBanana() //This is essentially what I would like to be able to do
  }
  else if(a is Giraffe){
    //Call a method specific to Giraffe
  }

}
```

So the animals share common functionality such as eat() and sleep() but what I am wondering is if there is way to call, for example, PeelBanana() from the monkey class, a method which does not exist in all derivations of the Animal class.

Comment: This is a typical example of violating object oriented programming rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to cast it first:

```
if(a is Monkey){
    ((Monkey)a).PeelBanana();
}
```

Be careful with this, though; if you find yourself having to cast objects like this there are probably flaws in your approach. Strictly speaking, if you are working with a `List<Animal>`, then all you should care about is the behaviour defined in `Animal`.

Comment: Thats exactly what I was was looking for. I tried (Monkey)a.PeelBanana() but this makes much more sense thanks.

Comment: Yeah I am kind of realising that now. In an ideal world, would I probably just create an abstract method, such as PrepareFood(), which the monkey can override to implement PeelBanana() functionality??

Comment: That sounds much more like it fits with proper OOP design principles, yes - assuming it applies to all subtypes of `Animal`.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest that you make `Animal` an abstract class and make `Monkey`, `Giraffe` and other animals implement common methods. It could look something like this:

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    public abstract void Eat();
    ...
}
public class Giraffe : Animal
{
    public override void Eat()
    {
        // Giraffe eating
    }
    ...
}
public class Monkey : Animal
{
    public override void Eat()
    {
        this.PeelBanana();
        this.EatBanana();   //Or something like this
    }
    ...
}
```

And then just do

```
foreach(Animal a in animalList.Values){
    a.Eat();
}
```

This is a much more object-oriented way of solving this.

Comment: +1 - it sounds like he's already come to this conclusion but this is exactly what I was getting at with my answer.

Comment: I marked @AntP question as the answer because it is essentially what I wanted in the original question but this question along with the comments has also prompted me to make some design changes. Thanks